# How can I resolve a C++ error when installing Pycaret in anaconda?

Tags: python, python-3.8, pycaret

I have an error when installing PyCaret using conda prompt as follows:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

ERROR: Could not build wheels for bottleneck which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

The error appears to be on the C++ version. I have run the following setup process bus the error still exists: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

I would really appreciate help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please post the whole traceback (even if huge).